# How can I download a folder from Google Drive in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, wget, google-drive, xubuntu

How can I download a directory from Google Drive to Ubuntu 20.04 with wget?

I searched and have not found a solution that works for me.

I tested this command:

```
 wget --no-check-certificate
 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-hgjZ3EkoHpp3EcdKQNdX4vS7V1Bbx9M'
-O FILENAME
```

But it only works for one file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the free and open-source
[drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive):

> `drive` is a tiny program to pull or push Google Drive files.

To download files or folders from google drive, use the command:

```
drive pull -id <file or folder id>
```

Comment: how can i install drive in my ubuntu ?

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/blob/master/platform_packages.md#ubuntu-or-ubuntu-based-distros), section "Ubuntu, or Ubuntu based distros".

Comment: i think that is not the best solution beacause i'm using docker so  when i execute "  sudo apt-get install drive" i get this error " E: Unable to locate package drive "

Comment: The problem is that the `drive` release is no longer in that repository. Try instead [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse), documented also in [Usage](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Usage).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I found to download large folders from google drive is gdrive:

- https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive
- https://github.com/glotlabs/gdrive

```bash
gdrive download --recursive --skip <file_id>
```

where `<file_id>` is the id you get from the folder URL. No need to configure anything, it will already ask you for your credentials and such.

The `--skip` flag is useful for large folders, since the download might time out at some point. You then rerun the command and `--skip` will make it act like an `rsync`.

As of this date, `--skip` is a relatively new flag and is available if you install `gdrive` through Go. If your system `gdrive` doesn't have it, try the same without `--skip`. Then, if you really need it, install it using `go get` as described in the github readme page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible with `wget`. I would recommend using the excellent `rclone` tool, which provides detailed instructions for [Google Drive](https://rclone.org/drive/).

```
# Assuming gdrive alias is gd
rclone copy gd:/path/to/file local_destination
```

Comment: To copy from remote shared folder, use: `rclone copy --drive-root-folder-id 1-XXX-YYY gd:/ .` (where `gd` is your configured remote).

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/DG02002/gdrivedl project with the following steps:

1. Install Python dependencies:

   ```
   pip3 install google-auth-oauthlib google-auth google-auth-httplib2 google-api-python-client
   ```
2. Enable Google Drive API
3. Create access [credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).

   Create OAuth client ID credentials, then Click Create Credentials > OAuth client ID. Click Application type > Desktop app.
4. Download JSON file with credentials.
5. Download Python script

   ```
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DG02002/gdrivedl/main/gdrivedl.py
   ```
6. Authenticate with your credentials.

   ```
   python gdrivedl.py --auth client-secret.json
   ```
7. To download file or folder, use: `python gdrivedl.py "link"` syntax.

Check README for more details.